# weird behavior from sqlInterpolate with 3 or more arguments

Tags: r, dbi

I can pass 2 parameters to sqlInterpolate just fine but things get wonky if I try passing three or more. Any wisdom?

For example:

```
# assume "conn" is a database connection

library(DBI)

sqlInterpolate(conn, "select a")
#> <SQL> select a

sqlInterpolate(conn, "select ?a", a="A")
#> <SQL> select 'A'

sqlInterpolate(conn, "select ?a ?b", a="A", b="B")
#> <SQL> select 'A' 'B'

sqlInterpolate(conn, "select ?a ?b ?c", a="A", b="B", c="C")
#> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
#>  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘sqlInterpolate’ for signature ‘"character"’

sqlInterpolate(conn, "select ?a ?b ?c d", a="A", b="B", c="C")
#> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
#>  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘sqlInterpolate’ for signature ‘"character"’

sqlInterpolate(conn, "select ?a ?b c ?d", a="A", b="B", d="D")
#> <SQL> select 'A' 'B' c 'D'
```

At first, I thought this function returned an error if you try to pass three parameters to it but that's clearly not true as per the last statement. So...I'm lost.

Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be a bug when using `c=` as a variable name, I suggest you raise a new [issue](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/issues) in the `DBI` package. It may be an issue for the specific driver, though I've verified it for `pool`, `odbc`, and `PqConnection` connection objects.

Comment: As an aside, I usually discourage `sqlInterpolate` in lieu of parameter-binding. `sqlInterpolate` is certainly safer than (say) `sprintf` or `paste`, but parameter-bind is intended to be much more secure, and take better advantage of sql compiler optimizations (if used).